# Jfrog container Resgistry

Tags: jfrog-container-registry

Please help me get over this issue. I finished installing Jfrog container registry from jfrog download website on my ubuntu server. when perform curl ip-add:8081 i get the welcome page but when i go through the browser, I get this start up image lingering. access log and router error logs are here attached. thanks for helping a brother [[[here is the logs and everything [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G048N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5EAh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ex1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ALXm.png)

more incite, i have tried adding ip to system.yaml but not working still. my localhsot is block for security reason, i can access the jfrog ui through the dns name but it does not warm up complete to start up ui . thanks